# How I can safely run async code, when handling messages from Messenger?

Tags: asynchronous, mvvm, windows-runtime, async-await, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM, inparticular MVVMLight. For boradcasting to all of my modelviews, that no internet connection is available I am using `Messenger` class. The modelviews subscribe to this event in order to reload itself with offline data, inform user etc.

However, I have a problem. When I have the folowing handler:

```
private void HandleNoInternetMessage(NoInternetAccessMessage obj)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await InitializeForOfflineInternalAsync());
}
public async Task InitializeForOfflineInternalAsync()
{
    try
    {
        WaitingLayerViewModel.ShouldBeVisible = true;
        WaitingLayerViewModel.IsBusy = true; //<--exception HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)
        bool switchToOffline = await CommonViewModelProvider.InformUserOfNoInternetAccessAndChangeAppState(); //<!- CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher is null
        await FilterTestItemViewModel.InitializeForOfflineAsync();
        await FilterTestItemViewModel.InitializeForOfflineAsync();
        WaitingLayerViewModel.ShouldBeVisible = false;
        WaitingLayerViewModel.IsBusy = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

I got exception HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD), because in `InitializeForOfflineInternalAsync` I am changing some properties of the viewmodel wchich are bound in XAML (or at least I think it is because of that). However, it is weird, because I am changing in other code bound properties regularly and have no problems with it (and the thread is a working thread).

Now, how can i solve that?

- The messanger let me provide only delegate which is not async (which make kind of sense), so I can not have the `HandleNoInternetMessage` method async
- I am using async await ... no explicit spawning of threads
- I dont have access in VM to Dispatcher, because I am in VM which should not know about platform dependent stuff. And when I tried to use it to show a message, NullPointer excpetion was thrown when calling `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;` And again when calling from other places, no such exception was thrown

I guess the question is How I can safely run async code, which changes boudn properties, when handling messages from `Messenger?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're responding to messages that are logically events, so this is an acceptable use case for `async void`.

```
private async void HandleNoInternetMessage(NoInternetAccessMessage obj)
{
    await InitializeForOfflineInternalAsync();
}

public async Task InitializeForOfflineInternalAsync()
{
    try
    {
        WaitingLayerViewModel.ShouldBeVisible = true;
        WaitingLayerViewModel.IsBusy = true;
        bool switchToOffline = await CommonViewModelProvider.InformUserOfNoInternetAccessAndChangeAppState();
        await FilterTestItemViewModel.InitializeForOfflineAsync();
        await FilterTestItemViewModel.InitializeForOfflineAsync();
        WaitingLayerViewModel.ShouldBeVisible = false;
        WaitingLayerViewModel.IsBusy = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember that [`Task.Run` is for CPU-bound code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html) (as I describe on my blog).

Comment: Thanks for your help. For anybody else, who is interested: I found one of your articles, which explained to me what I needed to know: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx . I was under impression that async void methods are bad practice to use no matter what. Now I understand it better, I hope. Also, the problem with RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD was cause byt the fact, that when there is a call to `Task.Run` it looses the synchronizationContext (DispatcherSynchronizationContext), which is able to access UI resources.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to the Guru Stephen Cleary, and despite that I know he wrote books and countless articles on the parallel programming world, and despite the fact that I am still planning to read his books, I can not prevent myself from disagreeing vehemently.

---

The view of `async void` causes me a panic attack, and will prevent me from sleeping at night (literally, not figuratively, I am not joking).

so I developed a small solution, but it worked great for me.

here is the extension class.

```
public static class PubSubEventsHandlerHelperExtension
{
    public static void HandleMessageWith<TPubSubEvent>(this TPubSubEvent message, Func<TPubSubEvent, Task> handlerFunc)
    {
        Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew(async (state) =>
        {
            if (state is not TPubSubEvent param)
                return;

            await handlerFunc(param);
        }, message);
    }
}
```

and here is the usage from the view-model

```
public class ViewModel : IRecipient<YourPubSubEvent>
{
    public void Receive(YourPubSubEvent message) =>
       message.HandleMessageWith(HandleYourPubSubEvent);
       
    private async Task HandleYourPubSubEvent(YourPubSubEvent message)
    {
        try
        {
            // you can await an async methods
            await Task.Delay(1);

            // if an exception occurs, the process will not crash
            // because of the `async void`
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // very important, you can not reach the UI thread directly here
            // you have to use dispatcher (or MainThread if you use MAUI)
            if (MainThread.IsMainThread)    // call from the UI Thread, so call the method directly.
                return ExecuteShowException(exception);

             // The call is NOT from the UI Thread, so we have to access the UI  from the UI Thread.
             return MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => ExecuteShowException(exception));        
        }
    }
}
```

a couple of words:

1. I tried throwing an exception and verified that the exception does not crash the process
2. Accessing the UI thread is possible, but not directly
   You have to use `Dispatcher` or `MainThread` depending on the platform you are in (WPF, MAUI) correspondingly.